What’s going on with John 7:16, “My teaching is not my own, but his who sent me”?
This seems unusual. Particularly, the odd part is “his who.” Is it correct to use a possessive and a relative pronoun in this way? If so, what similar phrases are also allowed?
It seems like this is not just a case like “The party is John’s, who turned 40 today” where we already know who John is and the clause with the relative pronoun “who” is tacking on more information.
In this case, the clause “The teaching is his” has an ambiguity around the word “his” and the clause “who came before me” is actually clearing up the ambiguity, specifying who that is.
A similar sentence might be “Victory is theirs who score the most home runs.”
Maybe even “Victory is the team’s that scores the most home runs.”
Any further analysis of this would be appreciated including whether it’s allowed or just archaic.

This is just one Bible translation, apparently the ESV? Maybe indicate that in your question. KJV has "My doctrine is not mine, but his that sent me."

This is similar to the possessive antecedent problem (or not-problem, depending on how you want to look at it).

@StuartF Agreed.  You can see many different translations of that verse here.  The only exact matches are the NASB (1971) and the Amplified Bible (1987) — neither of which should be anywhere near old enough for archaic language.  (But then there's a tradition of some Bible translations being archaic when published.  Even the KJV itself was!)  FWIW, the NLT is very clear: “I’m not teaching my own ideas, but those of God who sent me.”

It's comparable to

It's not my book, it's his.

But that assumes the listener knows who "his" refers to. In a face-to-face conversation you could point at him to make it clear.
But in the case you quoted, the referrent of "his" is not obvious, so the reflexive prepositional phrase "who sent me" identifies them.
This is not a very common construction, but you've probably seen phrases like "he who sent me". It's essentially the same except the pronoun is possessive in the Bible verse.

Yes. The Talmudist Ben Zoma asked: "Who is wise? He who learns from every human."

Does this mean that the two following examples are also correct? “Victory is theirs who score the most home runs.”
“Victory is the team’s that scores the most home runs.”

Yes. But it's an awkward phrase, so it's not idiomatic. "Victory belongs to the team that scores the most home runs."

@Matthew I would say the second of those is not grammatical, while the first is. The ’s genitive in English is a clitic that attaches to an entire noun phrase, and in both your examples, that NP includes the relative clause. The most by-the-book way of forming that possessive would thus be, »Victory is [they/the team] who score the most home runs’« (with runs’ being the plural runs and the possessive ’s clitic). When the relative pronoun’s antecedent is a plain noun (‘the team’), I’d say this is mandatory; when it’s a pronoun, either option is possible (but clunky and best avoided).

@JanusBahsJacquet While I agree it's technically grammatical, forming the posessive of such a long noun phrase like that is practically never done. While you can say "The cat in the hat's", don't try "The cat that ate the fish that swam in the aquarium's". "The cat's that ate..." may be ungrammatical, but it's more likely to be understood.

@Barmar I would generally avoid both for reasons of clunkiness, but I find “The cat that ate the fish that swam in the aquarium’s collar is too tight” much more natural and understandable than “The cat’s that ate the fish that swam in the aquarium collar is too tight”. The latter is utterly ungrammatical to me, to the point that it’s nearly unparsable in writing and would be completely unparsable in speech (where the first part would be heard as ‘the cats that ate the fish…’).

@JanusBahsJacquet In writing you could use ppunctuation: "The cat's -- that ate the fish ... -- collar is too tight."

That would perhaps make it easier to parse, but it would be stretching the limits of punctuation to breaking point, and I at least would consider it even clunkier than the undashed version.

Theodore Roosevelt [Good Reads] used this string:


The joy of living is his who has the heart to demand it.


As did Ralph Waldo Emerson [One Journey]:


The world is his who can see through its pretension.


Also Thomas à Kempis [Forbes]:


Great tranquility of heart is his who cares for neither praise nor blame.


And similarly, with a change in pronoun, the hymn-writer Frances Havergal [Hymntime]


And per­fect strength in weak­ness / Is theirs who lean on Thee.


It is probably dated.

This does strike me as old-fashioned, and the KJV has something similar ("his that sent me"). The New International Version has "My teaching is not my own. It comes from the one who sent me." That sounds more natural to the modern ear.
